# Java not showing last letter of string correctly?

Tags: java

So I have this little program and all it needs to do is check if the last letter of the last name is an "s". And if it is an "s" itll change the last name to plural.
Ex.
Smith = Smith's
Smiths = Smiths'

Changes the last name to plural. Simple right? Seems so, but my if statement isnt detecting if the last letter is an "s"

**Here's some code**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Lastname {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String messageText = null;
    String title = null;
    int messageType = 0;
    String lastName = "";
    String pluralLastName = "";

    Input input;

    input = new Input();

    messageText = "Please enter a last name. I'll make it plural.";
    title = "Plural Last Names";
    messageType = 3;

    lastName = input.getString(messageText,title,messageType);



    int intLength = lastName.length();
    String lastLetter = lastName.substring(intLength- 1);
    System.out.println("The last letter is: " + lastLetter);

    if (lastLetter.equals('s'))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The last name entered as plural is " + lastName + "'" );
    else 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The last name entered as plural is " + lastName + "'s" );




}}
```

The if statement always just adds an "'s" to everything.

Comment: Also, if you just want the last character, you could use `charAt()`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use double quotes to represent a `String` literal.

```
if (lastLetter.equals("s"))
```

Otherwise you are comparing a `String` with a `Character` which will always return `false`.

Comment: Wow. I knew it was simple. And it works now. Thanks!

Comment: You may also want to consider `"s".equals(lastLetter)` and possibly even `"s".equalsIgnoreCase(lastLetter)` but the idea is sound ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing Strings, you can compare chars:

```
char lastLetter = lastName.charAt(intLength- 1);
System.out.println("The last letter is: " + lastLetter);

if (lastLetter == 's')
```

Right now, you are comparing Strings to chars.